# "Place of Marriage" in New Jersey Marriage Index

Tags: marriage-records, new-jersey

I am looking at the New Jersey Marriage Indexes (available on Archive.org and Ancestry.com, and probably other places as well).  Here is a couple of example entries:

[image: Page header]

My question is about the two columns labeled "State File No." and "Place of Marriage".

- I assume (and would appreciate confirmation) that "State File No." denotes a box in the archives that contains the actual marriage documents, and is probably not really any use to me.
- I would also guess that somewhere there is a list of places in New Jersey with associated numbers, and the numbers seen here (7231, 7470, and 9307) refer to entries in that list.  **This list is what I'm looking to find.**  I looked at the beginning and the end of the microfilm reels, and they did not contain such an index.

If no one here on SE knows the answer, I can contact the NJ Archives, and maybe even answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

A web site on [NJ Vital Records](https://www.bringoutyerdead.com/genealogy-research-services/nj-place-codes/) has a [link to a PDF](http://www.bringoutyerdead.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/NJ-Vital-Records-Codes.pdf) which contains all the codes you are looking for. The 10 page PDF is organized by county, and then number. (The five digit codes brought up by the OP in comments are explained [on the web site.](https://www.bringoutyerdead.com/genealogy-research-services/nj-place-codes/#:%7E:text=Just%20to%20make%20things%20more%20confusing%C2%A0(because%20we%E2%80%99re%20New%20Jersey)%2C%20some%20years%20use%20a%20five%2Ddigit%20code.%20The%20location%20is%20identified%20by%20only%20the%20first%20four%20digits%20of%20this%20five%2Ddigit%20number.%20In%20the%20example%20I%E2%80%99ve%20illustrated%C2%A0here%2C%20the%20location%20listed%20as%200451(4)%20is%20Mount%20Ephraim%20in%20Camden%20County.))

Comment: Thank you!   However, the marriage that I'm looking at has a place number that is '16672', which doesn't appear to be in that document. :-(

Comment: Reading more at [www.bringoutyerdead.com](https://www.bringoutyerdead.com/genealogy-research-services/nj-place-codes/), who created that PDF, she says: 

> Just to make things more confusing (because we’re New Jersey), some years use a five-digit code. The location is identified by only the first four digits of this five-digit number.

and
 
> The codes in my PDF apply to later years, and won’t be useful in the 1901-1903 index.

Comment: Apparently in 1901-1903, the "place number" in the index was just a sequence number for the year.  Starting on 1-Jan with '1', and marching forward.  The wedding I'm looking at was (I believe) in November, and got '16672'